# What is the Brill font encoding? Or: \DeclareTextComposite in XeLaTeX

Tags: xetex, accents, font-encodings

I want to redefine `\'` for a few characters (e.g., so that `\'t` maps to **t’**). I once did this with \DeclareTextComposite (I think), which requires me to specify the encoding (`T1`, `OT1`, etc.). What is the encoding if I'm using XeLaTeX with Brill fonts. (I've ruled out `T1`, `OT1`, and a few others by trial and error.)

More generally, does XeLaTeX provide better ways to go about this reassignment of accent commands? will this approach be flexible enough to map a two character input (like `\'{ky}`) to a multicharacter output (like **kʸ’**).

—————————————————————

MWE shell:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{???}{t}{t'}
\setmainfont{Brill Roman}
\begin{document}
\'t
\end{document}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\v{t}`?

Comment: `\v` behaves differently for `t` and `p`, `c`, `k` (it adds a hacek for the latter).

Comment: (Also, even with `\v{t}`, I still need other accents to do other work. But let me know if there's something to `\v` that I'm missing.)

Comment: It would be better if you specify what's precisely your aim.

Comment: Ulrike's answer below is enough for me to figure the rest out. Thanks for being willing, but I don't want to waste your time!

Comment: AFAIU, `\v{d}` and `\v{t}` both refer to the caron háček accent (in this case, vertical caron, to be more precise). But when being typeset, the glyph should *look* like `d'` and `t'` (with apostrophe-look-alike attached to the right-upper corner of the letter). For example, the word “loďka” (“rowboat” in Czech) should be input as `lo\v{d}ka`.

Answer (score 4):

The encoding is TU, but the last argument of \DeclareTextComposite is a number (for the glyph/char position), so you can't it to get some combination. For this you can use \DeclareTextCompositeCommand (I don't have your font so I faked something). It only works for single chars as input.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{TU}{t}{65} % gives A
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{t}{blub}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\begin{document}
\'t
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works with the Brill font too.

Answer (score 2):

The command accepts Unicode arguments.

Very handy. Another way of mapping.

[image: blub]

And the last argument can take arbitrary code.

Note that `Brill` font contains spacing modifier letters and combining diacritical marks, so kʸʼ can be entered directly.

MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{TU}{u}{65}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{t}{b\textit{l}ub}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{x}{\textbf{bl\textcolor{red}{u}b}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{y}{\textbf{bl\textcolor{red}{i}b}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{z}{\fmanat }
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{Δ}{\textbf{bl\textcolor{red}{\textit{i}}b}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{ѭ}{\textsc{bl\textit{o}b}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{अ}{{\fmhiero \textcolor{red}{}}}
\DeclareTextCompositeCommand{\'}{TU}{ꦓ}{\tikz\node[rectangle,draw,fill=yellow!50](b){kʸʼ};}
\DeclareTextComposite{\'}{TU}{v}{30306}


\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Brill Roman}
\newfontface\fmcyr{Noto Serif}
\newfontface\fmdev{Noto Sans Devanagari}
\newfontface\fmhiero{Noto Sans Egyptian Hieroglyphs}
\newfontface\fmjav{Noto Sans Javanese}
\newfontface\fmanat{Noto Sans Anatolian Hieroglyphs}
\newfontface\fmzh{Noto Serif SC}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{cccccc}
\verb|\'t| & \verb|\'u| & \verb|\'x| & \verb|\'y| & \verb|\'Δ| & \verb|z| \\
\'t & \'u & \'x & \'y & \'Δ & z \\
    &  &  &  &  &  \\
\verb|\'|{\fmcyr ѭ} & \verb|\'|{\fmdev अ} & \verb|\'|{\fmjav ꦓ} & \tikz\node[circle,draw,fill=green!15,yshift=-1em](a){kʸʼ}; & \verb|\'v| &  \verb|\'z| \\
\'ѭ & \'अ & \'ꦓ & kʸʼ & {\fmzh\large \'v} & \'z \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Not an answer, of course; just a kitten playing with string.

Fortunately, the question was asked. And answered. Much appreciated to both.